# Importing packages correctly using python and a package called ArcREST

Tags: python, package

I'm a geographer using ArcGIS and in there I use Python too access and maintain my content on an online platform, called ArcGIS Online . To this end I use a Python package called ArcREST. The package contains several subfolders:

[ArcREST contents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dWBAm.png) (Figure 1)
From these I'd like to use the code in the subfolder WebMap by doing the following:

```
from arcrest import webmap
```

But this gives me the following error:

```
Runtime error

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "", line 1, in
File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.3\lib\site-packages\arcrest\webmap_init_.py", line 2, in
import domain

ImportError: No module named domain
```

I tracked the problem:
[WebMap **init**.py code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dbUON.png)
[WebMap-subfolder contents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fAVB9.png)

And tried to solve the problem bij doing the following:

```
import sys
from os import path
sys.path.append('.../ArcREST-master/src/arcrest/webmap')
from arcrest import webmap
```

However, this got me the following error:

```
Runtime error

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in
File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.3\lib\site-packages\arcrest\webmap_init_.py", line 2, in
import domain
File ".../ArcREST-master/ArcREST-master/src/arcrest/webmap\domain.py", line 6, in
from .._abstract.abstract import BaseDomain

ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package
```

The domain function is as follows and redirects to the abstract subfolder of ArcREST (see figure 1 again):
[domain.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LIPXJ.png)
[abstract.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sxzjB.png)

I think that I'm not importing parts of the package correctly, but I don't get what. Can someone please help me? I've wrecked my brain over this for some time now.. I'm using Python 2.7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, it seems that there are two versions of this package in PyPi: `arcrest` and `ARCRest_Package`. On windows at least, `arcrest` does not even include the `webmap` package :) while the `ARCREst_Package` does.

If you really have to work with that package, you can `git clone` it, or install the `ARCRest_Package`. However I tried both and I can assure you that the `webmap` package is absolutely not usable ;  once I fixed the `import domain` and similar imports with `from . import domain` and similar, I found another `AttributeError` in `domain.py` where the `range` `@property` is commented out while its setter is still un-commented... This is not working code :)

Since the [ArcREST git site](https://github.com/Esri/ArcREST) is now officially archived and redirects all users to [ArcGIS python API](https://developers.arcgis.com/python/), I would strongly recommend that you use the latter.

Comment: Ah that's a pity, but I'm really thankful that you looked into my problem! I'll try the Python API instead. Thanks again.